# Formatting a Query Output Into multiple rows

Tags: sql, format, google-bigquery, output

I have the following query:

```
#standardsql
WITH TT_bid_info as(
SELECT
DISTINCT
request_id,
revenue_ppc as ppc_avg_TT,
revenue_ppq as ppq_avg_TT
FROM a.quotes
WHERE request_id IN (Select request_id FROM a.quotes WHERE quotes.pro_user_id = 7271495)),

pro_bid_info as(
SELECT
DISTINCT
request_id,
revenue_ppc as ppc_avg_pro,
revenue_ppq as ppq_avg_pro
FROM a.quotes
WHERE request_id IN (Select request_id FROM a.quotes WHERE quotes.pro_user_id = 7271495)
AND pro_user_id = 7271495)

SELECT DISTINCT
round(avg(nullif(TT_bid_info.ppc_avg_TT,0)),2) as ppc_avg_tt,
round(avg(nullif(pro_bid_info.ppc_avg_pro,0)),2) as ppc_avg_pro,
round(avg(nullif(TT_bid_info.ppq_avg_TT,0)),2) as ppq_avg_tt,
round(avg(nullif(pro_bid_info.ppq_avg_pro,0)),2) as ppq_avg_pro
FROM TT_bid_info
JOIN pro_bid_info ON TT_bid_info.request_id = pro_bid_info.request_id
```

Which returns:

```
ppc_avg_tt|ppc_avg_pro|ppq_avg_tt|ppq_avg_pro
22.18     |   6.23    | null     |   4.3
```

However, I want something like:

```
      TT  | pro
    --------------
ppc|22.18 | 6.23
------------------
ppq|null  | 4.3
```

How would I go about doing this? My thoughts were to use something a "case when" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query in Question by itself is hard to dissect thus I will apply my answer to result only

So, there are really many ways to transpose row in your result into few rows. Below are just few examples:

```sql
#standardsql
WITH `yourResult` AS ( 
  SELECT 22.18 ppc_avg_tt, 6.23 ppc_avg_pro, NULL ppq_avg_tt, 4.3 ppq_avg_pro
)
SELECT 'ppc' type, ppc_avg_tt TT, ppc_avg_pro pro FROM `yourResult` UNION ALL
SELECT 'ppq' type, ppq_avg_tt TT, ppq_avg_pro pro FROM `yourResult`
```

OR

```sql
#standardsql
WITH `yourResult` AS ( 
  SELECT 22.18 ppc_avg_tt, 6.23 ppc_avg_pro, NULL ppq_avg_tt, 4.3 ppq_avg_pro
)
SELECT x.*
FROM `yourResult`, UNNEST([STRUCT<type STRING, TT FLOAT64, pro FLOAT64>
('ppc', ppc_avg_tt, ppc_avg_pro), ('ppq', ppq_avg_tt, ppq_avg_pro)]) x
```

Both resulted with

```sql
type    TT      pro  
ppc     22.18   6.23     
ppq     null    4.3
```

Of course ideally would be to adjust your query in first place to produce desired result right away. Hope you can apply above approaches to make it

Meantime, still wanted to point something about your query

Below fragment in your query

```sql
  SELECT DISTINCT
    request_id,
    revenue_ppc AS ppc_avg_pro,
    revenue_ppq AS ppq_avg_pro
  FROM `a.quotes`
  WHERE request_id IN (
    SELECT request_id 
    FROM `a.quotes` 
    WHERE pro_user_id = 7271495
  )
  AND pro_user_id = 7271495
```

is equivalent to below

```sql
  SELECT DISTINCT
    request_id,
    revenue_ppc AS ppc_avg_pro,
    revenue_ppq AS ppq_avg_pro
  FROM `a.quotes`
  WHERE pro_user_id = 7271495
```

This is just an example, It might be because you (most likely) tried to simplify your example  - but it makes it hard to answer  - so that is why I provided answer based on your result and not for the query itself

Comment: The first part of your answer, when added to the query, produced the exact results I wanted.

Comment: sure. please note: `type` here is just arbitrary field name I chose - you can use any appropriate alias for it